# add some head lines that vim will execute it automatic when open the file?

Tags: vim

I used to remember that we can add some vim cmd line in the file's head, and they will be executed when vim open the file.
I tried to add head line like this:

```
#vim map <F4> :close<CR>
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t add vim cmd line at the file head. If you have

```
set modeline modelines=N
```

where N>0 then lines like

```
vim: tw=40
```

at the start/end of the file (not more then N lines from the start/end) will set *option* tw (textwidth) to 40. You can write it in a fuller form:

```
vim: set textwidth=40
```

, but it still accepting only options (`set` here is just ignored). It does not even accept all options (some of them are stated in the doc as “cannot be set from a modeline … for security reasons”). Without plugins you can’t have generic command here. Note that if you find one that allows running `:map` command I will suggest not using it: it is very unsecure. I’ve seen only those that allow doing `:let` in modelines.

By the way,

1. why not put it into vimrc?
2. `:close` command can be typed as `<C-w>c` in close mode which is much faster then moving hands to `<F4>`.
3. Don’t use `map` without `nore` for no reason. Plain `map` makes you think “what will the new mapping I add break” before adding it. `*noremap` will make all mappings immune to breaking by any other mapping with different `{lhs}`.

Comment: 1. I want to add some special key mapping on a special file, and i don't want to make my vimrc file mess. <br/>
2. `:close` command is just an example, I was to make a complex key mapping.<br/>
3. thanks for you explain for `map` & `noremap`, that's helpful.